# Downloading and Storing Images in a Server Database

Tags: javascript, database, download

So currently my website is loading an JSON File from my server, looking for the data it needs and then showing it up on the screen as well as downloading and showing an image related to that info from a public API. I was wondering how would I go about storing the API downloaded image to my own servers database so before every image fetch it would check for the image in my server and if it doesn't exist, it would go to the public API and download and store it in my servers database?

---

This code below is a sample, when the site is loaded it pulls a random card from the JSON and displays its info along with the image. I want to download the image from the api, store it in my servers database and then check for said image before downloading as to reduce API calls to a minimum.

```
function RandomCard() {
const RC = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardAPIListings.data.length); 
var cardShowcase = document.getElementById("randomcardshowcase"); 
var randomCardImage = document.getElementById('randomImage'); 
  switch (cardAPIListings.data[RC].type) { 
    case "Spell Card": 
    case "Trap Card":

    cardShowcase.innerHTML = '\"' +cardAPIListings.data[RC].name + '\"' + '<br><br>' +  '[' +
    cardAPIListings.data[RC].race + ' / ' + cardAPIListings.data[RC].type + ']' + '<br>' + 
    'Attri: ' + cardAPIListings.data[RC].attribute + '<br><br>' + 'Effect: ' + '<br>' + 
    cardAPIListings.data[RC].desc;
      
    randomCardImage.src = cardAPIListings.data[RC].card_images[0].image_url;
    break;
```

---

Edit:
The PUBLIC API that I'm using says this:

[ Card Images
Users who pull our card images directly from our server instead of our google cloud repository will be immediately blacklisted.

Card images can be pulled from our Google Cloud server but please only pull an image **once** and then store it locally`(I Assume this means Store it in your Own Server/API Database)`.
*If we find you are pulling a very high volume of images per second then your IP will be blacklisted and blocked.*]

---

So I need a way to store the images in my own location as they are being downloaded from the Public API so I Dont get blacklisted.

Comment: what is your backend?  it could be as easy as a text file containing all of the pairings between image_path and data. have an endpoint of /image_data?id=xxxxx. (or via POST, whatever). then in there, check the file for the mapping. if it exists, serve the info. if it doesn't, access the API, save the result to the file, and send the info. Obviously a file isn't maybe the best choice. a DB like mysql, sqlite, mongodb and others could be a better fit.

Comment: @Yarin_007 My backend is Just a Github Pages site that stores My Json At the moment, Nothing else. I Am not a back end developer so I Dont know the most about Stuff like this. I Dont know how to save images using javascript and store them.

Comment: @NotTayyy The question is a bit vague. Not knowing what you are using as a server. Are you just implementing a frontend that is making requests to the public api? or do you have your own api which is calling google's api? If it is the latter then it is simple, all you need is create a repository which exposes a function say `getImageById(imageId)` this function will then look for the image in its system cache (could be memory backed by disk) if not found then fetch it from the public api. If however, you don't have your own backend, well the best you can do is cache on the client.

Comment: I will try to write a full answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, only store images and other binary data to the file system.
No reason to burden database with big binary data. Only store file link (or URL) in the database.

Comment: I Edited for clarity

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).